# Driving servo with the help of microcontroller

Tags: avr, servo

I'm making a driver board for servo TowerPro MG946R based on ATtiny13. PWM parameters have been taken from manuals: signal period ~13 ms, pulse width ~540us - ~2400us (checked on oscilloscope), but servo doesn't breathe.

On [this site](http://www.servodatabase.com/servo/towerpro/mg946r) there is a parameter Pulse cycle - 1 ms. I've read somewhere that this high frequency can kill servo. Should i try it?

Also is there some dependence of power supply voltage level for servo and voltage level of PWM signal? Mine are 6V for power and 4.8 for signal.

Comment: as of now the question is too broad...  did u check the servos with a servo tester...  are pinouts correct..  if u once connected in reverse the servo is most probably busted....

Comment: @SurajBhawal thanks for answer. I'm trying to find a servo tester around my location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in separated DC sources i was using for driver board and servo. DC source should be single.

Answer (score 1):

1ms is the (defacto standard) center position for servos, with 0 being one end and 2ms being the other. You can retain the 13ms period if you like, but the high duration must be in that range if you want the servo to operate properly.